# Android- how to get the url of the webView?

Tags: webview, geturl

I have a Subview that loads a `WebView`, and I want to get the URL of the `WebView` when my `WebView` loads a site.

Can you tell me how to get the URL of the `WebView`? The method `webView.getUrl();` does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

```
String theUrl;
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webView);

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        theUrl = url;
    }

});

webView.loadUrl(myURL);
```

Comment: if i use this: String a= url.toString();
        a = webView.getUrl();

Comment: @user3310711 in my code you are sure page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this overridden method of WebViewClient()

```
String currentPageUrl;

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            currentPageUrl = url;
        }
    });

Log.d(TAG,currentPageUrl);
```